# FCM XMPP vs HTTP reliability

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I would like to ask, please, if anybody tested and experienced FCM XMPP vs FCM V1 over HTTP.

- How is the **push reliability** of XMPP comparing to FCM - both on iOS and Android?
- How do they compare when Android is in *doze* or in *standby*?
- How do they compare on iOS?

Any suggested more reliable services?

Reliability is:

```
p devices that received a push
------------------------------ = R
n devices to were sent a push
```

Thanks

Comment: I too would like to know if XMPP is the preferred method for connecting with FCM for bulk messaging where latency (low) is critical. Our VMs are taking way too much time and CPU using Firebase admin sdk which I am guessing is using HTTP under the hood. Any references, links etc appreciated in this regard.

Comment: From what I know, I suspect that it may work on modern phones only when the app is in foreground (in front, when the screen is on! Not only by FgService). In any other circumstances the device may be asleep and you won't be able to reconnect the socket on time. I hoped I may be wrong but I don't see much references to XMPP application. **I think I saw somewhere that it's deprecated**

Comment: I guess FCM may very well have its own persistent XMPP connection with the device regardless of the connection method between FCM and app server and so I doubt the app being in f/bg would matter.